# Is there any way to not generate fields in the serilog log?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog

.Net + Serilog

So, I need to **disable** the generation of **all** fields that are in the **message** (in all logs), i.e:

`_logger.LogInformation("GetAccount successfully finished. Account data: {@GetAccountResponse}", getAccountData);`

Will produce this log:

```
{
    "level": "Information",
    "messageTemplate": "GetAccount successfully finished. Account data: {@GetAccountResponse}",
    "message": "GetAccount successfully finished. Account data: GetAccountResponse { UserId: \"8f984424-b0d8-482b-9c74-9b136506b613\", UserName: \"4d0d755c-03a6-4202-a93d-3383c8570422\" }",
    "fields": {
        "GetAccountResponse": {
            "_typeTag": "GetAccountResponse",
            "UserId": "8f984424-b0d8-482b-9c74-9b136506b613",
            "UserName": "4d0d755c-03a6-4202-a93d-3383c8570422"
        },
        "RequestId": "0HMT7O94RP6PS",
        "RequestPath": "/1.0/deliver",
        ... (make it simple)
    }
}
```

How can i get rid of all objects in "fileds", that I passed as arguments to the log, BUT save it in "message":

```
{
    "level": "Information",
    "messageTemplate": "GetAccount successfully finished. Account data: {@GetAccountResponse}",
    "message": "GetAccount successfully finished. Account data: GetAccountResponse { UserId: \"8f984424-b0d8-482b-9c74-9b136506b613\", UserName: \"4d0d755c-03a6-4202-a93d-3383c8570422\" }",
    "fields": {
        **->> HERE WE GET RID OF ARGUMETS, BUT SAVE IT IN MESSAGE**
        "RequestId": "0HMT7O94RP6PS",
        "RequestPath": "/1.0/deliver",
        ... (make it simple)
    }
}
```

Maybe some kind of this logic present in destructurama?